# Dropped computer, Windows 7 Startup Repair irregular

Tags: windows-7, windows, troubleshooting

I'm having some issues with my computer (Lenovo T420) and startup repair. I've looked at a few other threads, but I'm unsure about some things with my situation. I knocked my computer off a table yesterday afternoon - I'm not sure if it had already shut down (it was shutting down), but it was off after dropping. I turned it on a few hours later and startup didn't happen, and I got to recovery options.

I ran startup repair, with the standard messages (scanned for problems, repaired for half an hour or so, and restarted). I got to the recovery again, and started startup repair again (with the message below the moving blue bar of something like - "Attempting repairs, may take more than an hour"_. Unfortunately my computer ran out of batteries, so powered off - I plugged it in and the startup repair began again, eventually with the message "Attempting repairs, may take more than an hour".

Two hours later, my computer restarted, and went back to startup repair, with the same "more than an hour" message below.

It ran for the next 6 hours while I slept, however this time, below the bar, it says "Attempting repairs..." and does not specify any time - I'm not sure if this is significant. It's still running (about 14 hours in total since I first started Startup Repair) - I'm using another computer at the moment.

Another issue right now is my external hard drive with my backup stopped working a couple of weeks ago, and I was actually planning to do a new backup last night!

From reading other threads concerned with Startup Repair, it sounds like my hard drive may be toast. However, I'd like to ask:

1. Has anyone run startup repair in a similar situation for longer than this, with it working in the end and fixing the drive?
2. If I take it to a software shop I take for some minor issues, would they possibly be able to do anything?
3. I've seen briefly a solution of making a Windows 7 Repair Disc. I assume I could make this off a colleague's, but is this likely to help?
4. Is there any other advice that anyone can give me as to what to do to diagnose or fix the exact problem?
5. Is it advisable to just turn it off and try another option such as using a Windows Installation Disk (if I can find it)? The problem is I can't stop the repair, so the only way for me to stop it is the power button.

Comment: The SpinRite program can sometimes repair a problem like this as a last resort after you've recovered the data from the hard drive. While checking this website for answers about using SpinRite I found: [Laptop fallen - Need help to diagnose HDD](http://superuser.com/questions/650370/laptop-fallen-need-help-to-diagnose-hdd). I don't know if your software shop has a copy of SpinRite, but even if it doesn't you could buy it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Karel - they weren't able to salvage it, but I'll look into Spinrite after copying the data onto the new hard drive (They tried using a recovery programme to copy it into my new hard drive but that didn't work).